# Were Thestrals involved in the creation of Harry's cloak?

Tags: harry-potter

Can someone check my logic.

Given that:

- Harry's cloak is a Deathly Hallow supposedly taken from Death.
- Thestrals can only be seen by people who have seen death.

Would the alchemical preparation of said cloak have involved Thestrals?

Comment: Again, I'd like to remind whoever is voting to close this as POB that we do not close questions just because they don't have an explicit canon answer.

Comment: Logically, your points don't imply your conclusion.

Answer (score 7):

When studying Thestrals in Care of magical Creatures in *Order of the Phoenix*, no mention is made of Thestral involvement in the making of Invisibility Cloaks. In *Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them*, the entry for Thestrals similarly makes no mention of any use relating to Invisibility Cloaks. This is perhaps notable because in other entries such things *are* discussed. The entry for Demiguise states:

> Demiguise pelts are highly valued as the hair may be spun into Invisibility Cloaks.

Of course, if the use of Thestrals was unique to Harry's Invisibility Cloak then it is possible that no one mentioned it because no one knew about it. But if no one knew about it, we also wouldn't know about it.

In any case, I think the premise of the question is a bit of a stretch. Even if we would grant that the Invisibility Cloak truly came from Death, there is no *prima facie* reason to think that the Cloak has something to do with Thestrals. The Cloak supposedly made Death invisible, and Thestrals are invisible to those who have not seen death, but why *would* there be any connection between those two facts?

Answer (score 3):

**We don't know**.

We're not really in possession of any facts about the process of the creation of the Hallows. It's not really mentioned in the books, besides for the fable of meeting Death. I checked the story in *Tales of Beedle the Bard* as well. No information there either.

At the end of *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*, Dumbledore mentions that it's probable that the Peverall brothers simply created the objects. The [Pottermore](https://www.pottermore.com/explore-the-story/the-deathly-hallows) article on them also says that they were likely created by the Peveralls.

> "So it's true?" asked Harry. "All of it? The Peverall brothers —"
>   "— were the three brothers of the tale," said Dumbledore, nodding. "Oh yes, I think so. Whether they met Death on a lonely road... I think it more likely that the Peverall brothers were simply gifted, dangerous wizards who succeeded in creating those powerful objects. The story of them being Death's own Hallows seems to me the sort of legend that might have sprung up around such creations.["]
>   <sub>*Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*, chapter 35:" King's Cross"</sub>

However, we don't have any details on the process of their creation.

Comment: I would tend to agree, though it is worth noting that the Elder Wand has thestral hair as it's core, so thestrals were involved in the making of at least some of the Hallows.